# How to do "getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled" at onCreateView()

Tags: android

I can do it at onCreate(). But I can't do at `onCreateView()`. I occur error at ---

```
myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);        
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**Code:**

```
public class Register extends Fragment {

DatabaseHelper myDB;
EditText username, email, password;
Button save;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_register, container, false);
    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    username = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etRegisterUserName);
    email = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etRegisterEmail);
    password = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etRegisterPassword);
    save = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bSave);        
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because `Fragment` doesn't provide a `getSupportActionBar()` method, it's a method of the `AppCompatActivity` (ActionBarActivity is deprecated) that hosts the fragment. Use `getActivity().getSupportActionBar()` to get a reference to it if using `onCreateView`

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lot. I got it

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```